# How to bind string column data

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to write a php script to compare rows from the database and then adds the values together if payment_id are matches. Based on payment_id:

Example:

```
   +----+------------+-----------+--------+
   | id | payment_id | cheque_id | amount |
   +----+------------+-----------+--------+
   |  1 | 1000       | MB101     | 20     |
   |  2 | 1000       | MB102     | 20     |
   |  3 | 1111       | MB113     | 20     |
   +----+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Result required

```
   +------+--------------+----+
   | 1000 |  MB101/MB102 | 40 |
   | 1111 |  MB113       | 20 |
   +------+--------------+----+
```

Trying to merge cheque column as string. For 'Amount' column I know that should be use SUM.

Any suggestions is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GROUP BY`

```
select payment_id,group_concat(cheque_id SEPARATOR '/') as cheque_ids,
SUM(amount) as amount
FROM table name
GROUP BY payment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
SELECT payment_id, group_concat(cheque_id SEPARATOR '/') AS cheque_ids,
SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY payment_id
```